# Get software center updates install status from sccm client using powershell

Tags: powershell, sccm, patch

I want to get the real time status of all patches currently in the SCCM Client Software center.  I've attempted to use multiple scripts I've found online but none of them end up showing me real time results.  I can get all the currently available updates and well as their corresponding software update groups that are deploying those missing patches but have not yet discovered how to link the missing patches to their current status like Software Center currently does.

The function below currently works and is what I use to install the missing patches.

```
Function Install-SCCMPatchesAvailable {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(
      Position = 0,
      Mandatory = $false,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
      HelpMessage = "Do not reboot server after patches install")]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [switch]
    $DoNotReboot
  )

  begin {
    Write-Verbose "Install-SCCMPatchesAvailable: Started"
  }

  process {
    try {
      ([wmiclass]'ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK:CCM_SoftwareUpdatesManager').InstallUpdates([System.Management.ManagementObject[]] `
        (Get-WmiObject -Query 'SELECT * FROM CCM_SoftwareUpdate' -namespace 'ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK'))

      while (-not((Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK' -Class 'CCM_ClientUtilities' -list).DetermineIfRebootPending().RebootPending)) {
        $Time = (get-date).ToShortTimeString()
        Write-Output "Still Patching @ $Time"
        Start-Sleep -s 60
      }
      if (-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('DoNotReboot')) {
        if ((Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK' -Class 'CCM_ClientUtilities' -list).DetermineIfRebootPending().RebootPending) {
          (Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK' -Class 'CCM_ClientUtilities' -list).RestartComputer()
        }
      }
    }
    catch {
      Write-Error -Message "Something went wrong with Install-SCCMPatchesAvailable.`n`nError.Exception.Message : $($_.Exception.Message)`nError.Exception.FullName: $($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)"
    }
  }

  end {
    Write-Verbose "Install-SCCMPatchesAvailable: Completed"
  }
} #End Install-SCCMPatchesAvailable
```

I would like to replace:

```
$Time = (get-date).ToShortTimeString()
Write-Output "Still Patching @ $Time"
Start-Sleep -s 60
```

With something showing the patches listed in the sccm software center and their corresponding patch status (Downloading, installing, pending verification, needs reboot, etc...), which the software center shows using its GUI interface.

I can also view any missing updates using a module I wrote that returns one or more missing patches objects.  However, the `Status` for the object can only show `Missing` or `Installed`.  Not the actual SCCM status of the patch.  Example:

```
SCCMPatchDeploymentName  : .MS_Server_Engineering_Patch_Testing - Post Basline OSs QAC 
                           Testing
ComputerName             : FSL04231
__GENUS                  : 2
__CLASS                  : CCM_UpdateStatus
__SUPERCLASS             : 
__DYNASTY                : CCM_UpdateStatus
__RELPATH                : CCM_UpdateStatus.UniqueId="5dc25e3e-31b9-4ac7-b1b7-a62a982139
                           0d"
__PROPERTY_COUNT         : 15
__DERIVATION             : {}
__SERVER                 : FSL04231
__NAMESPACE              : ROOT\ccm\SoftwareUpdates\UpdatesStore
__PATH                   : \\FSL04231\ROOT\ccm\SoftwareUpdates\UpdatesStore:CCM_UpdateSt
                           atus.UniqueId="5dc25e3e-31b9-4ac7-b1b7-a62a9821390d"
Article                  : 4088787
Bulletin                 : 
ExcludeForStateReporting : False
Language                 : 
ProductID                : 0fa1201d-4330-4fa8-8ae9-b877473b6441
RevisionNumber           : 202
ScanTime                 : 20180516214114.000000+000
Sources                  : {{7D052A75-2032-4F02-BAC9-9EDA4DBD58DE}}
SourceType               : 2
SourceUniqueId           : {7D052A75-2032-4F02-BAC9-9EDA4DBD58DE}
SourceVersion            : 82
Status                   : Missing
Title                    : 2018-03 Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2016 for 
                           x64-based Systems (KB4088787)
UniqueId                 : 5dc25e3e-31b9-4ac7-b1b7-a62a9821390d
UpdateClassification     : 0fa1201d-4330-4fa8-8ae9-b877473b6441
PSComputerName           : FSL04231
```

Comment: I don't really understand. You already know that the status you want  (Downloading, installing, pending verification, needs reboot, etc...) is the evaluationstate of CCM_SoftwareUpdate, so what are you even looking for? Do you just need the code to translate the evalstate into a human readable form?

Comment: I'd like to know the same as you, the status of updates installation in a remote Sofware Center. did you find any 'tool' or PS as you were looking for? Thank you very much
Nacho

Answer (score 0):

Software Centre displays progress for software installs and advertisements. It does not show patch status other than Installed/Missing, so I suspect if you want to enumerate the progress status for that patch, you'll need to scrape logs to determine if the client is doing anything with each respective patch to create a calculated status message at runtime.

Comment: Software Center shows more than just installed/missing.  Software center in regards to patches can display the following list of evaluation states. 

    12=InstallComplete
    11=Verifying
    10=WaitReboot
    9=PendingHardReboot
    8=PendingSoftReboot
    7=Installing
    6=WaitInstall
    5=Downloading
    4=PreDownload
    3=Detecting
    2=Submitted
    1=Available
    0=None

Comment: AFAIK Those states are limited to software deployment & installation. If you want to understand the status of a Windows update beyond the compliance states provided out-of-the-box, you will need to calculate it at runtime by scraping logs. You can read more about the process here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/sum/understand/software-updates-introduction#BKMK_SUMCompliance